# Internal USB camera: what is SH?

Tags: laptop, usb, webcam

I have a replacement of the internal USB camera for the laptop Acer Aspire 5750G. AFAIK USB has only 4 connections (5V, D+, D-, GND). On the PCB of the camera I noticed there are 5.
They are labeled: 3.3V, D+, D-, GND and SH. Does anyone know what is "SH" connection for? It seems that it's just connected to GND but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, SH is not in the USB specs: http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml - It could be something like you see here: http://pinoutsguide.com/DigitalCameras/olympus-c70z_pinout.shtml - SH could stand for shell, which is a GND connection.

Comment: This could probably be migrated to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ for better results.

Comment: Cut open any USB cable you have lying around. You will find five connections.

Comment: I think it's shield (or shell) ground connection, it makes sense. Thank's for the answers. I didn't know about electronics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it is a `shield ground`.